# Как вытащить данные внутри Спринг Теста?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

У меня есть сервис, в котором используется в ДТО, хочу написать под него тест, но при попытки вытащить данные получаю NULL_POINTER_EXCEPTION

Метод внутри сервиса который хочу протестировать

```
@Transactional
    public Long addStudent(CreateStudentDto dto){
        Account account = new Account();
        if (isAccountExist(dto.getEmail())){
           account = accountRepository.findAccountByEmail(dto.getEmail());
           return studentRepository.findStudentByIdAccount(account).getId();
        }
        else {
            String generatePassword = generatePassword();
            String generateSalt = salt();
            String hashPassword = hashString(generatePassword,generateSalt);
            account.setRole((byte)1);
            account.setPassword(hashPassword);
            account.setSalt(generateSalt);
            account.setIsActive(true);
            if (Objects.nonNull(dto.getEmail())) account.setEmail(dto.getEmail());
            accountRepository.save(account);
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setIdAccount(account);
            studentRepository.save(student);
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(account.getEmail())){
                String message = "Your password - " + generatePassword;

                mailSender.send(account.getEmail(),"Test Registration", message);
            }
            return student.getId();
        }
    }
```

Мой тест-класс

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
    public class StudentServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    @MockBean
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;
    @MockBean
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;
    @MockBean
    private MailSender mailSender;

    @Test
    public void addStudent() {
        CreateStudentDto dto = new CreateStudentDto();
        dto.setEmail("dsds@gdd");
        studentService.addStudent(dto);
        Account account = accountRepository.findAccountByEmail(dto.getEmail());
        when(accountRepository.findAccountByEmail(dto.getEmail())).thenReturn(account);
        when(accountRepository.save(account)).thenReturn(account);
        Assert.assertNotNull(dto.getEmail());
        Assert.assertTrue(CoreMatchers.is(account.getRole()) // GET = NULL
                .matches(Collections.singleton((byte)1)));
        Assert.assertTrue(account.getIsActive()); // GET = NULL
        Mockito.verify(mailSender, Mockito.times(1))
                .send(ArgumentMatchers.eq(dto.getEmail()),
                        ArgumentMatchers.eq("Test Registration"),
                        ArgumentMatchers.contains("Your password - "));
    }
```

При попытки получить роль аккаунта(account.getRole()), я получаю NULL, хотя внутри сервиса прописана роль, но данные не вытягиваются, что я делаю неправильно?

Добавил accountRepository

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account,Long> {
    Account findAccountByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: @RomanKonoval в методе addStudent() задается значение ROLE, account.setRole((byte)1); Внутри теста, я вызываю этот метод studentService.addStudent(dto) и по Email, который я задал я могу получить аккаунт;и как мне кажется теперь могу вытянуть значения ROLE account.getRole()), но по всей это не так

Comment: @RomanKonoval getRole

Comment: @RomanKonoval у меня отрабатывают все сервисы и контроллеры, какой смысл проверять репозитории

Comment: @RomanKonoval не знаю, что еще нужно добавить. я добавил часть кода где потенциальная ошибка может быть `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
    public class StudentServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    @MockBean
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;
    @MockBean
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;
    @MockBean
    private MailSender mailSender;` возможно аннтоации неправильно отрабатывают и аккаунт просто напросто не сохраняется во время применения addStudent  и поэтому потом не вытягивается ROLE

Comment: @RomanKonoval извиняюсь, что сразу не добавил. Хочу уточнить, а что значит настройка взаимодействия с моков и где она настраивается?

Comment: @RomanKonoval то есть мне внутри тест-метода нужно прописать `when(accountRepository.findAccountByEmail(dto.getEmail())).thenReturn(account);`

Comment: @RomanKonoval добавил полный код теста и сервиса, может это прояснит что-то, пока не понимаю как верно подойти к тестам

Comment: @RomanKonoval проверил с помощью Optional, мое добавление аккаунта внутри теста - не куда не добавляет Аккаунт и в итоге при попытке получить аккаунт по емейлу возращается NULL. Вопрос: почему метод внутри теста не добавляет в accountRepository ничего, хотя в сервисе все работает правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала я объясню, как работают моки и как их использовать в тестах.

Когда в тесте, который запускается с помощью `SpringRunner`, какое-то поле помечено аннотацией `@MockBean`, то соответствующий бин в контексте спринга замещается моком. Это значит, что в контексте, который создается при запуске тесте, нет реальной реализации `AccountRepository` (т.е. той, которая сохраняет в базу данных или какое там сконфигурированное хранилище). Этот мок будет внедрен как зависимость в бины, которые используют `AccountRepository` (в нашем случае в `StudentService`).

Что же такое мок? Это объект, который реализует указанный интерфейс (для `accountRepository` это `AccountRepository`) и, каждый метод которого ничего не делает и по-умолчанию возвращает значение по умолчанию.

Рассмотрим на примере `AccountRepository`.

Если мок не конфигурировать, то вызов `findAccountByEmail` ничего сделает (в смысле не сохранит объект в БД) и вернет значение по умолчанию для `Account`, т.е. `null` (для всех объектных типов это будет `null`, а для примитивов типа `int` - `0`, `boolean - false` и т.д. [см таблицу](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)).

Именно поэтому вызов:

```
Account account = accountRepository.findAccountByEmail(dto.getEmail());
```

в тесте возвращает `null`.

Тепер вкратце, зачем моки нужны.

Реализация класса `StudentService` зависит от других классов, в частности от `AccountRepository`. Для тестирования `StudentService` хочется:

1. его изолировать от зависимостей, т.е. чтобы тестировать именно логику самого класса, а не логику еще и `AccountRepository` и других
2. эмулировать ситуации, которые не всегда можно предсказуемо добиться в реальной системе (например, сбой сетевого подключения)

Для этого используются моки, т.е. "подделки". Суть в том, что перед выполнением тестового кода, мы их конфигурируем (или настраиваем), чтобы они делали, то что нам нужно для данного тестового сценария. Например, мы может указать, что при вызове `findAccountByEmail` должен вернуться `null`, так как `account`-а с такой почтой не существует.

Дополнительно после выполнения кода, который тестируется, мы можем проверить, что метод мока был вызван с параметрами, которые мы ожидаем в данном тестовом сценарии (например, что была установлена правильная роль).

Смотрим на пример из вопроса. Тут тест среди прочего должен проверить. что если не существует `account`-а с заданным почтовым адресом, то он будет создан и у него будет  определенная роль.

Тест именно этого сценария будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
@Test
public void addStudentCreatesNewAccount() {
  String someEmail = 'some@email.com'

  // тут я предполагаю, что isAccountExists пользуется findAccountByEmail
  // чтобы определить существует ли account с заданой почтой
  when(accountRepository.findAccountByEmail(someEmail)).thenReturn(null);

  CreateStudentDto dto = new CreateStudentDto();
  dto.setEmail(someEmail);
  studentService.addStudent(dto);
  
  // ArgumentCaptor позволяет захватить и запомнить значение, которое
  // было передано, как аргумент в метод мока, чтобы его проверить
  ArgumentCaptor<Account> accountCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Account.class);
  verify(accountRepository).save(accountCaptor.capture());
  Account savedAccount = accountCaptor.getValue();
  assertThat(savedAccount.getRole(), equalTo((byte)1));
  assertThat(savedAccount.getEmail(), equalTo(someEmail)); 
}
```

Пример, только чтобы понять принцип. На практике, например, я `ArgumentCaptor` не использую, а пользуюсь `MockitoHamcrest.argThat` + матчеры. Далее, конфигурацию моков прячу в более высокоуровневые методы типа:

```
void givenAccountForEmailDoesNotExist(String email) {
   when(accountRepository.findAccountByEmail(someEmail)).thenReturn(null);
}
```

и т.д. Главный принцип - спрятать детали реализации и сделать тест более читаемым и менее зависимым от деталей реализации.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, теперь начинаю "въезжать", мое представление было далеко не верное.

Answer (score -1):

Если я не ошибаюсь, `@RunWith(XXXXX.class)` это достаточно старая аннотация и можно не использовать. `@SpringBootTest` будет сверх достаточно в вашем классе.

Вместо `CrudRepository` используйте `JpaRepository`. Вам дополнительно будет доступно `flush()`, `saveAndFlush()`, `getOne()`. При тестировании, эти вещи очень помогают. Старайтесь так же не использовать `@Transactional`. Используйте его лишь там, где он реально нужен (к примеру при написании `void deleteBy` в файле репозитории)

Как я понимаю, `@Transactional` вы добавили из-за того, что у вас выползает ошибка в районе строки `accountRepository.save(account);` или `return studentRepository.findStudentByIdAccount(account).getId();`. Вот как я бы написал бы:

```java
public Long addStudent(CreateStudentDto dto){
        Account account = new Account();
        if (isAccountExist(dto.getEmail())){
           account = accountRepository.findAccountByEmail(dto.getEmail());
           accountRepository.flush();
           Student student = studentRepository.findStudentByIdAccount(account).getId()
           return student;
        }
        else {
            String generatePassword = generatePassword();
            String generateSalt = salt();
            String hashPassword = hashString(generatePassword,generateSalt);
            account.setRole((byte)1);
            account.setPassword(hashPassword);
            account.setSalt(generateSalt);
            account.setIsActive(true);
            if (Objects.nonNull(dto.getEmail())) account.setEmail(dto.getEmail());
            accountRepository.saveAndFlush(account); //добавил "saveAndFlush()"
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setIdAccount(account);
            studentRepository.saveAndFlush(student);
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(account.getEmail())){
                String message = "Your password - " + generatePassword;
                mailSender.send(account.getEmail(),"Test Registration", message);
            }
            return student.getId();
        }
    }
```

Так же меня интересует, почему от `Student` нельзя никак попасть в таблицу `Account`? Это абсолютно никак не связанные таблицы? Или между ними все-таки есть аннотация `@OneToOne` (как пример)?

Comment: CrudRepository было решено использовать командой, впервые работаем со спрингом( учебная практика), внутри таблицы Student хранится idAccount(OneToOne), в Account хранится ROLE. @Transactional использую по совету ментора ибо сохраняются два объекта в разные таблицы(как я понял)

Comment: @Ross Могли бы вы прикрепить сюда сущность student и account? Уверен, там допущены ошибки

Comment: CrudRepostiry является ЧАСТЬЮ JpaRepostiry) Проблем при смене с Crud на Jpa не будет! [Вот тут найдете](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014086/what-is-difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-interfaces-in-spring) ответ разницы Crud и Jpa.

Comment: @Ross использование `@Transactional` в рандомных местах и без здравого смысла может привести к плохим последствиям. К примеру, если вы будете тестить добавление пользователя в таблицу, то ваши данные из-за `@Transactional` не будут туда добавлены, хотя тест будет на 100% пройден. И будет непонятно куда деваются данные

Comment: @Ross также, я порекомендовал бы отдельно тестировать все. Отдельно тестировать репозитории, отдельно service-слой, отдельно контроллеры. Исходя из вашего вопроса, вы решили все засунуть в один тест, что является не самым лучшим тестированием. Лучше написать на 10 тестов больше, но зато программа будет 100% работать

Comment: И почему бы Вашей команде не использовать JUnit5? он же более новее JUnit4... JUnit4 был выпущен аж в 2006 году, а JUnit5 - 2017...

Comment: спасибо за советы, увы завтра уже сдача финального проэкта,сервисы и контроллеры переделывать нет времени, осталось доделать тесты. В будущем постораюсь более граммотные подходы использовать

Comment: Ух... Удачи тогда! @Ross

Comment: спасибо! наша команда - студенты, которые ранее не работали со спрингом) Поэтому я уверен некоторые решения можно сделать лучше, но в силу не опытности даже не понимаем этого)

Comment: Совет про неиспользование `@Transactional` без каких-либо объяснений - очень вредный. Как вы предлагаете без `@Transactional` делать атомарные изменения, вот хотя бы сохранение `Account` и `Student`?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Я не успел скинуть ссылку на статьи. Как я понял, данному пользователю этот вопрос уже не будет интересен

Comment: про сохранение `Student` и `Account`, тут стоило использовать `flush()` и `saveAndFlush()`. Однако, в его примере 100% допущена ошибка и она кроется в том, что вместо того, чтобы работать с объектами через обращение к ним в форме `student.getAccount().getId()`, они решили использовать лишнее обращение к БД

Comment: Дело ведь не в авторе вопроса. Ответ будет здесь еще долго вводить в заблуждение читателей.

Comment: Объясните, как `flush` обеспечит атомарность?

Comment: Про `@Transactinal` - его не стоит пихать в каждую зависимость, где выпадает ошибка, связанная с прокси, а даже если не выпадает - тем более не стоит

Comment: @RomanKonoval простите, с данной терминалогией на русском я не знаком

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110584/discussion-between-roman-konoval-and-antonio112009).