# JUnit Test service слоя springboot, servis не видит объект в базе

Tags: java, spring-boot, юнит-тесты, junit

Опыта в написании тестов нету. Подскажите, что я делаю не так
Код теста

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class ShopServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private ShopServiceImpl shopService;
    @Mock
    private ShopDao shopDao;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShopFindByName() {
        String name = "Магазин велосипедов";
        Shop shop1 = shopDao.findByName("Магазин велосипедов");
        assertEquals(name, shop1.getName());
 
    }
}
```

выбрасывает NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.amr.project.model.entity.Shop.getName()" because "shop1" is null

    at com.amr.project.service.ShopServiceTest.testShopFindByName(ShopServiceTest.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:99)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:105)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:40)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

И тест не проходит естественно

Comment: Это дубликат вопроса: [Как вытащить данные внутри Спринг Теста?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152376/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%a1%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%a2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0) Там я подробно ответил почему это случается и как исправить

Answer (score 0):

Нужно "подставить" в замоканный объект `ShopDao` результат, который будет возвращаться при вызове метода `findByName`:

```java
@Test
public void testShopFindByName() {
    String name = "Магазин велосипедов";

    // в данном тесте DAO должно вернуть некий требуемый объект
    when(shopDao.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(new Shop(name));

    Shop shop1 = shopDao.findByName(name);
    assertEquals(name, shop1.getName());
}

@Test
public void testShopNotFoundByName() {
    // в данном тесте DAO должно вернуть некий требуемый объект
    when(shopDao.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(null);

    Shop shop1 = shopDao.findByName("любой");
    assertNull(shop1);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)